# How to avoid appcrashes in Android 9 with AmazonSNSClient?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, apache-commons-logging, android-9.0-pie

In Android 9 (API 28) my App crashes when creating a new AmazonSNSClient (in API 26 I don't get any errors):

```
AmazonSNSClient pushClient = new AmazonSNSClient(credentialsProvider);
```

My LogCat says:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<clinit>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:55)
        at myapp.service.AWSMessagingService.createEndpoint(AWSMessagingService.java:170)
        at myapp.service.AWSMessagingService.registerWithSNS(AWSMessagingService.java:103)
        at myapp.service.PushNotificationService.sendRegistrationToAWS(PushNotificationService.java:109)
        at myapp.service.PushNotificationService.onNewToken(PushNotificationService.java:105)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source:86)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<clinit>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:55) 
        at myapp.service.AWSMessagingService.createEndpoint(AWSMessagingService.java:170) 
        at myapp.service.AWSMessagingService.registerWithSNS(AWSMessagingService.java:103) 
        at myapp.service.PushNotificationService.sendRegistrationToAWS(PushNotificationService.java:109) 
        at myapp.service.PushNotificationService.onNewToken(PushNotificationService.java:105) 
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source:86) 
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:7) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2018-12-17 09:25:07.483 10291-10344/myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/myapp-grqOb2dmxK1zDq9u44b9Rg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I found out that I can avoid the error if I don't exclude "commons-logging" from "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns" in my build.gradle, so I replaced:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.0', {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

with:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.0'
```

The app works fine now but I can't build a signed APK because I get
the error "DuplicatePlatformClasses: Duplicate Platform Classes" and
my Lint Report says:

> commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now
>   provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or
>   alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example,
>   for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or
>   repackaging the library using something like jarjar. There are a
>   number of libraries that duplicate not just functionality of the
>   Android platform but using the exact same class names as the ones
>   provided in Android -- for example the apache http classes. This can
>   lead to unexpected crashes.
>
> To solve this, you need to either find a newer version of the library
>   which no longer has this problem, or to repackage the library (and all
>   of its dependencies) using something like the jarjar tool, or finally,
>   rewriting the code to use different APIs (for example, for http code,
>   consider using HttpUrlConnection or a library like okhttp). Note: This
>   issue has an associated quickfix operation in Android Studio and
>   IntelliJ IDEA. To suppress this error, use the issue id
>   "DuplicatePlatformClasses" as explained in the Suppressing Warnings
>   and Errors section.

So I ran "gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt" in the terminal in my project folder and found out that "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.0" uses "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1" but I can also find "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2" which is "provided by Android" I guess?

So why does "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.0" not use "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2" if I exclude "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1" and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the error by updating "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.0" to a newer version (in my case "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.9.1").

The NoClassDefFoundError in Android 9 is also tracked in this issue:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/476

Comment: never -> newer.

Comment: The issue https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/476 has been fixed in 2.6.30 version of the SDK.